# Postgres Data Encryption at Rest Using LUKS with dm-crypt

Tags: postgresql, encryption

We are trying to encrypt Postgres data at rest. Can't find any documentation to encrypt Postgres data folder using LUKS with dm-encrypt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No special instructions are necessary – PostgreSQL will use the opened encrypted filesystem just like any other file system. Just point `initdb` to a directory in the opened file system, and it will create a PostgreSQL cluster there.

Automatic server restarts will fail, because you need to enter the passphrase.

Of all the ways to protect a database, encrypting the file system is the least useful:

- Usually, attacks on a database happen via the client, normally with SQL injection. Encrypring the file system won't help.
- The other common attack vector are backups. Backups done with `pg_dump` or `pg_basebackup` are not encrypted.

But I guess you know why you need it.

Comment: We have taken care of SQL Injections and storing PII/confidential data using pgcrypto. We do store backups after encrypting the data. We work with banks and they have requirement of data encryption at rest. Thats where I was looking for File Level Encryption.

Comment: If we keep file system opened and somebody copies the folder from one system to other system. Will copied data work or ask for passphrase?

Comment: I don't know LUKS, but I expect that once the file system is opened, you can just copy the data. It will only protect you from thieves that rip out your hard disk.

Comment: Thanks for your help Laurenz. I need to do more research on this.